# How do I find undefined functions and add/link them as external functions?

Tags: c, linker, cortex-m, iar

I'm new to IAR workbenches in general (and EWARM to be precise), so I have a couple of potentially silly questions.
For starters, here's what I actually want to do and the questions aroused:

1. I need to check *.o (.obj)* file for undefined symbols and potentially collect them. When I was workings with GCC, I used *nm* with `--undefined-only` option to list such symbols. So, is there a similar tool in IAR (EWARM)?
2. Having these undefined symbols collected, I need to manually link these symbols (functions) to specific addresses. While working with GCC I used *ld* script and placed `function = address` entries in ENTRY part of the script. So, what's the right way to do the same thing in EWARM?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no direct way of doing this using only the tools from the EWARM distribution but since iccarm produces ELF-files you can continue using `nm --undefined-only` for this step.
2. There are at least two different ways of doing this. First, there is a command-line option to *ilink* that allows you to define symbol to address mappings. For instance, adding `--define_symbol print=0x1234` will add the symbol print with the value 0x1234. Second, symbols can be defined in the linker configuration file (`.icf`-file) using the `define exported symbol` directive. The example above is expressed as `define exported symbol print = 0x1234`.